# Linphone Android native sdk not ready yet

Tags: android-studio, linphone, linphone-sdk

1. I use git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive
2. I follow instruction on https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/ and download lastest SDK and NDK
3. I set path  -> sudo gedit ~/.bashrc and add last line with :

> export ANDROID_HOME=/home/onysevensmarts/Android/Sdk 
>   export ANDROID_NDK=/home/onysevensmarts/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle 
>   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools 
>   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools 
>   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_NDK 
>   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME

4.I've just install Install yasm, nasm , python, pkg_config, doxygen, graphviz and cmake 3.14 .
5.At Root direktori , execute command ./prepare.py 
 showing message :

> Configure project :liblinphone-sdk
>   native sdk not ready yet

6.Then I Download last liblinphone (liblinphone-android-sdk-4.0.1.zip) at https://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone

7.I extract them, there are 3 files 
  - liblinphone-sdk-javadoc.jar,
  - liblinphone-sdk-release.aar,
  - liblinphone-sdk-sources.jar.
8. I copy them to liblinphone-sdk folder on root direktory project.
9. I try ./prepare.py againt and still show error : **native sdk not ready yet**.

Where i do wrong? , and i try to 'make' , this error still show, 
i try open on Android Studio and i build , error message path=""

Anyone ever see this case, help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
   ./sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" 
   https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html
2. if number 1 error, do : export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
3. if repositories.cfg not found ,then : touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg
4. sudo pip install pystache
5. if pip not found : sudo apt install python-pip
6. pip install pystache
7. run 'make'
8. try to 'make install' and make sure android device connected debugging with your PC.